# How do you increase the timeout for an SSIS script task

Tags: ssis, timeout, script-task

I have a script task that is hitting the default timeout, which appears to be 10 minutes. To increase this do you have to do it within the script or is there a setting somewhere, similar to how you can set it on the connection manager? I don't have much C# experience and this script component was not written by me. Here is (mostly) what I see in the script component

The script:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.ServiceModel;
#endregion

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{


    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called once, before rows begin to be processed in the data flow.
    ///
    /// You can remove this method if you don't need to do anything here.
    /// </summary>
    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called after all the rows have passed through this component.
    ///
    /// You can delete this method if you don't need to do anything here.
    /// </summary>
    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        /*
         * Add your code here
         */
    }

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        /*
          Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
          For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
        */

        NetTcpBinding bindingElement = new NetTcpBinding();
        bindingElement.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
        bindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
        bindingElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
        bindingElement.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0);
        bindingElement.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0);
        bindingElement.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0);
        bindingElement.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(5, 30, 0);
        EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(Variables.InventorySumURL));

        SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.CallContext context = new SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.CallContext();
        SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.KMW_HighJump_InventSumServiceClient serviceClient = new SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.KMW_HighJump_InventSumServiceClient(bindingElement, endPointAddress);

        serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = Variables.UserName;
        serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = Variables.Password;

        SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.AxdKMW_HighJump_InventSum inventSumDoc = new SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.AxdKMW_HighJump_InventSum();
        SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.EntityKey[] responseKeys = new SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.EntityKey[1];
        SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.AxdKMW_HighJump_InventSum response;

        using (serviceClient)
        {
            SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.QueryCriteria criteria = new SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.QueryCriteria();
            SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.CriteriaElement criteriaelement = new SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.CriteriaElement();
            criteriaelement.DataSourceName = "InventSum";
            criteriaelement.FieldName = "ItemId";
            criteriaelement.Operator = SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.Operator.Greater;
            criteriaelement.Value1 = "";
            //criteriaelement.Operator = SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.Operator.Equal;
            //criteriaelement.Value1 = "10143-1210";

            criteria.CriteriaElement = new SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.CriteriaElement[1] { criteriaelement };
            inventSumDoc = serviceClient.find(context, criteria);

            foreach (SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.AxdEntity_InventSum records in inventSumDoc.InventSum)
            {
                SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.AxdEntity_InventDim inventDim = new SC_80dea46b524746348cc2db14ad9a8cec.AXService.AxdEntity_InventDim();
                inventDim = records.InventDim[0];

                decimal quantity = 0;

                AXInventoryBuffer.AddRow();
                AXInventoryBuffer.ItemID = records.ItemId.ToString();//.TrimEnd('\r','\n').Trim();
                AXInventoryBuffer.Warehouse = inventDim.InventLocationId.ToString();
                if (Decimal.TryParse(records.AvailPhysical.ToString(), out quantity))
                {
                    AXInventoryBuffer.Quantity = quantity;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It sure looks like you've defined a host of Timeouts to 5 hours and 30 minutes there in your `bindingElement`  section. I'd be curious to see what call is actually raising the time out exception

Comment: This comment is not to increase your timeout but a suggested alternative. Can you reduce the scope of your request to get quicker response and then make more requests? For example, if you are requesting for a month, can you make 30 daily calls? I see you have a foreach. Can you request foreach instead of getting them all at once?

Comment: This might take this a little over the top, but since you are in c# now, you might want to consider implementing my above comment within an Action Block which runs asynchronously. This can't be done in SSIS.